# what is the right R query to perform select?

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I want to select count of number of rows where `total[,3] >=0.7` and `total[,4] <= 0.3`.

`total` is a data frame and `total[,i]` denotes the `i`th column.

I wrote the following query:

```
nrow(total[,3]>=0.7 & total[,4]<=0.3)
```

but this gives me null

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### dplyr solution:

Using the `dplyr` package:

```
filter(total, total[,3] >= 0.7 & total[,4] <= 0.3) %>% summarise( count = n() )
```

or more explicit/readeable version:

```
total %>% filter(col3_name >= 0.7 & col4_name <= 0.3) %>% summarise( count = n() )
```

Visit: http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html for more info.

### Brief explanation:

`total` data frame is *filtered* for rows that meet the conditions inside `filter()` and the result is summarised by the `n()` function which returns the number of observations (rows in this case).

*note: substitute the name of column 3/4 for col3_name and col4_name.*

### Why this way?

`dplyr` was designed to be a fast + easy way of manipulating tabular data.

Comment: how do you specify columns by their column number in `dplyr` like OP asks?

Answer (score 2):

Or more commonly

```
sum(total[,3]>=0.7 & total[,4]<=0.3)
```

When you treat TRUE/FALSE values as numeric values, the TRUE evaluates to 1 and the FALSE to 0.

Though technically the which method as it is written is robust to NA values. If you want to ignore NA values, with `sum`, you can do

```
sum(total[,3]>=0.7 & total[,4]<=0.3, na.rm=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

length(which(total[,3]>=0.7 & total[,4]<=0.3))